# PHP Automatically upload images in folder

Tags: php, html

I'm really beginner in web programming. I want to make webpage which contain photo gallery. This is the code

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="clearfix">
        </header>
        <div class="main">
            <a class="fancybox" href="gallery/1.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="gallery/1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            <a class="fancybox" href="gallery/2.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Etiam quis mi eu elit temp"><img src="gallery/2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            <a class="fancybox" href="gallery/3.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Cras neque mi, semper leon"><img src="gallery/3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            <a class="fancybox" href="gallery/4.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="gallery/4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            <a class="fancybox" href="gallery/5.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Etiam quis mi eu elit temp"><img src="gallery/5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            <a class="fancybox" href="gallery/6.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Cras neque mi, semper leon"><img src="gallery/6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            <a class="fancybox" href="gallery/7.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="gallery/7.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have to type the name of photos manually. But it will be tired if the amount of photos is too much.
I want to add php code to upload those images from a folder automatically.
How to use php code inside the

```
<div class="main"></div>
```

Please give me example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your `<div>`:
`<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="clearfix">
        </header>
        <div class="main">
            <?php
                $image_array = array_diff(scandir("images"), array('..', '.'));
                $i = 0;
                foreach ($image_array as $key) { ?>
            <a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo 'images/'.$key; ?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">
                <img src="<?php echo 'images/'.$key; ?>" alt="" height="150" width="150"/></a>
            <?php $i++; } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>`
Change images to your folder name.

Comment: i have tried the code, the webpage just showing these symbol "; } ?>

Comment: Do you open with Web server or just HTML>?

Comment: i use xampp and the apache service has been started, and i try the code in new file, just this code in the body tag. And images appear with the actual size

Comment: Have you setting your width images in your CSS? You must try @jitendra parmar answer. I think it had completed

Comment: the result is same with your way, that gives me symbol "; } ?>

Comment: Use <?php not <?=. Have you use `<?php`

Comment: This is completely work for me. Don't use <?= but use `<?php`. Copy paste in your localhost my update code.

Comment: Oh thank you, i used your code in my old file and doesn't work, but i create new file it works. Okay i must learn another thing, thank you

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake, i think why the code doesn't work in my old file because the format is .html and the code works in .php file

Answer (score 0):

This should be use full

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="clearfix">
        </header>
        <div class="main">
            <?php
                $image_array = array_diff(scandir("YOUR IMAGES FOLDER NAME"), array('..', '.'));
                $i = 0;
                foreach ($image_array as $key) { ?>
            <a class="fancybox" href="<?= 'YOUR IMAGES FOLDER NAME/'.$key ?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"><img src="<?= 'YOUR IMAGES FOLDER NAME/'.$key ?>" alt="" height="150" width="150"/></a>
            <?php $i++; } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i have tried the code, the webpage just showing these symbol "; } ?>

Answer (score 0):

you can use `PHP RecursiveDirectoryIterator`

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="clearfix">
        </header>
        <div class="main">
        <?php $images = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('images');
        foreach($images as $img){
        if(is_dir($img->getFileName())){ continue; }
            echo '<a class="fancybox" href="folder/'.$img->getFileName().'" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="'.$img->getFileName().'"><img src="folder/'.$img->getFileName().'" alt="'.$img->getFileName().'" /></a>';
        }?>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this is not valid - as each element in the loop will only contain private methods